# Access stack vars with dynamic index wasm (wat)

Tags: arrays, webassembly

I am attempting to access indexed stack vars in wasm with dynamic values but I'm not sure how to do it.

```
(module
  (import "console" "log" (func $log (param i32)))
  (func $main

    ;;array (sorta)
    (local i32);; allocate 0
    (local.set 0 (i32.const 1));; set to value 1

    (local i32);; allocate 1
    (local.set 1 (i32.const 2));; set to value 2

    
    (local.get (local.get 0));;error here
    call $log
  )
  (start $main)
)
```

This causes errors

Is `(local.get 0)` *just* a variable name or can I ever send a dynamic value.

In the example above I was expecting to print the value of 2

Comment: `await WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(fetch(url), { console });` is on the js side btw

Answer (score 0):

the answer for making your own array is this:

```
(module
  (import "console" "log" (func $log (param i32)))
  (memory $memory 1)

  (func $main
    (i32.store (i32.const 0 ) (i32.const 0))
    (i32.store (i32.const 4 ) (i32.const 5))
    (i32.store (i32.const 8 ) (i32.const 3))
    (i32.store (i32.const 12 ) (i32.const 2))
    (i32.store (i32.const 16 ) (i32.const 1))
    (i32.store (i32.const 20 ) (i32.const 4))

    (i32.load 
       (i32.mul (i32.const 4) 
          (i32.load 
              (i32.mul (i32.const 4) 
                   (i32.const 2)
             )
          )
       )
    )
    call $log
  )
  (start $main)
)
```

this prints 2. first load gets 3. second load gets 2 (the value at index 3)